# iOS swift 0 key/pair value for a non-empty dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I think there's a bug with the compiler, and I hope there's a way to solve it.
In my AppDelegate, I have to create [String:String] dictionary, but nothing happen.
Stranger and stranger, I can retrieve the key-value pair with print (see the screenshot), but my dictionaries are still empty.
As you can see, I've tried with dictionary in different scope...no change
And I've cleaned. No change. And if I try in an other projet...it works...
Please, tell me I don't have to restart my projet with new files...Is there a way to fix the bug ?

[image: my screenShot]

EDIT : It seems to be a problem with Simulator, since my code works on a real device...

Comment: If this is still actual issue, you might want to log a bug to the Swift JIRA: https://bugs.swift.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa